# How is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}= \log 2?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

How is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}= \log 2?$$

I haven't done sequences in a long time, therefore proving this seems almost impossible. How is this sum gotten. Help very much appreciated.

Comment: Look up the Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: I thought about this earlier, but couldn't put it together.

Comment: That, plus Abel's theorem to show that the series is still equal to the function at points on the circle of convergence where the series converges.

Comment: hint: $\ln 2 = \ln(1+1)$

Comment: Hi Professor Israel, I also worked this problem out a few days ago, but using pretty much only the technique that Harry uses in his answer below.  I swapped a finite integral with a finite sum (leaving the limit outside for the moment), then used dominated convergence theorem to move the limit inside of the integral.

Comment: The result is just integration of the (convergent) sum 1/(1+x), over the interval [0,1], or, integration of 1/u over the interval [1,2], which gives the ln(2), as needed.  Do you think that there is anything missing from this approach, i.e., do I still need Abel's theorem?  The logic of my work seems fine and I think complete, but I just want to be sure -- I could have overlooked something important.  Thanks @RobertIsrael.

Comment: And proceeding in this way, there was no need to worry about the convergence on the circle / boundary, I think, @RobertIsrael.

Comment: Yes, you can do it this way, since the partial sums are uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n} &= x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} \\
& = x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int x^{n-1} dx \\
& = x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int x^n dx \\
& = x \int \left ( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \right ) dx \\
& = x \int \left ( \frac{1}{1-x} \right ) dx \\
& = -x \log \vert 1-x \vert \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 So, f(-1) &= -(-1) \log |1-(-1)| \\
& = \log(2)
\end{align*}

Comment: Isn't $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ when $|x|<1$